# Symfony2 - Managing Entity Relations To Unused Entities When Persisting

Tags: php, symfony, orm, entity, symfony-2.4

I have two entities (Customer & PhoneNumber) which are in realtion with each other via a ManyToMany connection.

When trying to display both entities in one form, I use the following statements:

```
$customer = new Customer();
$customer->addPhoneNumber(new PhoneNumber());
$form = $this->createForm(new CustomerType(), $customer, array(
    'action' => $this->generateUrl('customer_add'),
));
```

After validation of the form I need to check whether or not the PhoneNumber section in the form has been used or not as entering a phone number is not a requirement. The reason I need to do so is: When trying to persist a customer that has a PhoneNumber-Entity connected to it which has no values set (= NULL values), I get a NOT NULL-Error from the database.

So what I do is: After validating the form, I remove the PhoneNumber-Entity-Relation to the customer in case no phone number has been entered.

```
$phoneNumber = $customer->getPhoneNumbers()->first();
if(empty($phoneNumber->getPrefix()) && empty($phoneNumber->getNumber())) {
    $customer->removePhoneNumber($phoneNumber);
}
```

That causes the following problems:

- I no longer have a relation to a phone number entity. Now I have to do various check-ups on the relationships of the customer-entity each time I'm using it.
- Also I don't like the fact that I'm editing the customer entity after validating it successfully.
- In case an entity has a lot of relations to other entities, this adding and removing process I'm doing here can get very ugly and confusing.

Is there a better way to do what I am trying to do here?

---

Customer.php:

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\PhoneNumber", mappedBy="customers", cascade={"persist"})
 * @Assert\Valid()
 **/
protected $phoneNumbers;
```

PhoneNumber.php:

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Customer", inversedBy="phoneNumbers", cascade={"persist"})
 * @ORM\JoinTable(name="cp_relation")
 **/
protected $customers;
```

CustomerType.php:

```
# ...
->add('phoneNumbers', 'collection', array(
          'type' => new PhoneNumberType(),
          'options' => array(
              'required' => false,
          )
     ))
```

Comment: dump your form & entity mapping here, or read this document: http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/collection.html

Comment: Done - Maybe it has something to do with delete_empty and allow_delete but I am not sure if this will fully fix the problems I stated.

Comment: Ok, just so I got my mind set right: Enabling delete_empty will remove all empty forms in case no data was inserted in those fields. In order to be able to edit the customers later and maybe remove the phone number I will have to turn on allow_delete. With that set and by also assuring a consistent database-relation when editing customers everything should work properly?

Comment: by use allow_add, you no need that set a customer phone number. `$customer = new Customer();
$customer->addPhoneNumber(new PhoneNumber());`

Comment: But don't I need that part to show the user the fields in the template?

Comment: use prototype & jquery for that show user fields

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75555/discussion-between-chris-and-ghanbari).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As discussed in chat room, the best solution is that use `collection type` and set `allow_add=true` and by use of `jQuery` & `prototype` field, let user to add fields.

But in your case(because you don't want use `jquery` and rely on `js`), you can render static field as (don't forget to set `allow_add=true`):

```
<input type="email" id="form_emails_0" name="form[emails][0]" value="" /><br>
<input type="email" id="form_emails_1" name="form[emails][1]" value="" />
```